# What is this connector type and how to connect to a loose wire

Tags: connector

I have a 3d printer heater cartridge that terminates with a rather odd connector.  The heater cartridge is 30W at 24V.  But I am wondering what kind of connector this is and how to connect a loose wire to it, can anyone identify?

[image: connector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a wire ferrule. It's crimped on and provides a better connection in screw terminals than bare stranded wire. It provides a solid profile vs stranded wire so less likely they will shift and loosen and pull out or for heat cycling to be as problematic. Also makes less likely a rogue strand will short out to something else because its all inside the ferrule body.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_wire_ferrule

If you are trying to join it to another wire, you may be able to solder to it or just cut it off. You may be better off using an appropriate in-between connector like a screw block or terminal block or wago connector.

Comment: can one use a butt splice connector with this?

Comment: Maybe. Depends on the gauge of the ferrule and the wire. Mismatching the size leads to bad connections and in a heater thats not good. But also its not designed for that. Cut strip and then use the butt connector if you have the correct crimper.

Comment: it's effectively half of a butt splice connector already.  crimping over crimping seems kind of dodgy to me. it might be better to cut it off and do a fresh crimp.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a ferrule, it's intended to be inserted into a terminal block.